When using the method of substituting variables to find the limit, why can we still use the original numbers that need to be approximated?
I'm trying to solve this problem:

Assume $$f(x+\frac{1}{x}) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$$ then $$\lim_{x\to 3} f(x) = ?$$

I saw the answer is

$$t = x+\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 3} f(x) = \lim_{t\to 3} t^2 - 2 = 7$$

I am a little confused, since we have set $t=x+\frac{1}{x}$, why $x\to 3$ doesn't become $t\to \frac{10}{3}$?
This question may be a bit low-level, but I am really not good at math. Thank you for your help!

The trick is to realize that the function is $f(t) = t^2 - 2$ on the corresponding domain. The answer is very horrendously phrased.

@CalvinLin You mean, as long as the relationship is $f$, no matter what the variables are, it is consistent with $x\to 3$? What I don't quite understand is why the numbers to be approximated don't change correspondingly in the process from $x+\frac{1}{x}$ to $x$. Thanks for your help!

Correct. $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 3} f(x) = \lim_{y \rightarrow 3 } f(y) $.  $\quad$ What the solution is trying to express is: $\lim_{x + \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 3 } f(x + \frac{1}{x} ) = \lim_{x + \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 3} x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = \lim_{x + \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 3} (x + \frac{1}{x})^2 - 2 = 7$.

@CalvinLin I understand the problem, thank you for your help! :D

@CalvinLin Probably a dumb question, but how do you get ² – 2 from that?  Presumably from squaring  + 1/, and spotting the function result within that — but how do you know to try that?  Just intuition?

@gidds Mainly familiarity with algebraic manipulation. EG It is known that $x^n + 1/x^n$ can be written as a polynomial in $ x + 1/x$.

What the solution is trying to express is:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3 } f(x) = \lim_{x + \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 3 } f(x + \tfrac{1}{x} ) = \lim_{x + \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 3} x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = \lim_{x + \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 3} (x + \tfrac{1}{x})^2 - 2 = 7.$$

There is an accepted answer, but I will write here another way to look at what's going on. You are given
$$f\left(x+\frac1x\right)=x^2+\frac1{x^2}$$
and asked $\lim_{x\to3}f(x)$. Let me just switch variables then things will be more clear. Say we are given
$$f\left(t+\frac1t\right)=t^2+\frac1{t^2}$$
Now, you want to find $\lim_{x\to3}f(x)$, which basically reads: "As the input of $f$ goes to $3$, what does the output go to?". You cannot have $x\to 3$ and $x+\frac1x\to3$ at the same time. The source of the confusion for you is simply using $x$ for two different things. Writing it with $t$ makes sense.
Anyway, once you show $f(t)=t^2-2$, you get the limit as $3^2-2$ (input is $x$ and $t+\frac1t$ in our notation and formula).
Hope this helps. :)

Yeah you're right. I mistakenly confused parameters with unknowns. Thank you :)
